# Conditional user defined macro in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008, there are predefined macros, that can be used in the build process. For example I can set the output directory to `$(SolutionDir)\..\BIN\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)`. I was wondering if it will be possible to define a macro .. let's say `$(RuntimeLibrary)`, that will hold the corresponding value whenever I have defined the runtime library as `Multi-threaded Debug Dll`, `Multi-threaded Debug` and so on. 
I know that user macros can be added in VS 2008, but I can add only one value to a macro. I do not have conditions. I want something like:

```
<if> Runtime Library <is> "Multi-threaded Debug Dll"
    $(RuntimeLibrary) = "MDd
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. The buildsystem pre VS2010 isn't that extensible. I was wondering though: normally you have one build configuration for MDd, one for MD etc? At least if you want to keep things manageable.. So if you add a different property sheet to each config you can there define RuntimeLibrary. Or set the output dir directly.